# Scipy Newton with derivative: TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pydev, anaconda

I have a problem with scipy's newton method. I get an error when I use newton with a derivative given (see below for the error output).

I'm trying to compute the root of x**2 with a starting value of x0 = 2.0:

```
def test_newtonRaphson():
def f(x):
    resf = x**2
    return resf
assert(derivative(f, 1.0)) == 2.0
assert(round(newton(f, 0.0), 10)) == 0.0
dfx0 = derivative(f, 2.0)
assert(round(newton(f, 2.0, dfx0), 10)) == 0.0
```

The whole error ouptut follows:

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
```

`func = <function f at 0x04049EF0>, x0 = 2.0, fprime = 4.0, args = ()
tol = 1.48e-08, maxiter = 50, fprime2 = None`

```
def newton(func, x0, fprime=None, args=(), tol=1.48e-8, maxiter=50,
           fprime2=None):
    """
    Find a zero using the Newton-Raphson or secant method.

    Find a zero of the function `func` given a nearby starting point `x0`.
    The Newton-Raphson method is used if the derivative `fprime` of `func`
    is provided, otherwise the secant method is used.  If the second order
    derivate `fprime2` of `func` is provided, parabolic Halley's method
    is used.

    Parameters
    ----------
    func : function
        The function whose zero is wanted. It must be a function of a
        single variable of the form f(x,a,b,c...), where a,b,c... are extra
        arguments that can be passed in the `args` parameter.
    x0 : float
        An initial estimate of the zero that should be somewhere near the
        actual zero.
    fprime : function, optional
        The derivative of the function when available and convenient. If it
        is None (default), then the secant method is used.
    args : tuple, optional
        Extra arguments to be used in the function call.
    tol : float, optional
        The allowable error of the zero value.
    maxiter : int, optional
        Maximum number of iterations.
    fprime2 : function, optional
        The second order derivative of the function when available and
        convenient. If it is None (default), then the normal Newton-Raphson
        or the secant method is used. If it is given, parabolic Halley's
        method is used.

    Returns
    -------
    zero : float
        Estimated location where function is zero.

    See Also
    --------
    brentq, brenth, ridder, bisect
    fsolve : find zeroes in n dimensions.

    Notes
    -----
    The convergence rate of the Newton-Raphson method is quadratic,
    the Halley method is cubic, and the secant method is
    sub-quadratic.  This means that if the function is well behaved
    the actual error in the estimated zero is approximately the square
    (cube for Halley) of the requested tolerance up to roundoff
    error. However, the stopping criterion used here is the step size
    and there is no guarantee that a zero has been found. Consequently
    the result should be verified. Safer algorithms are brentq,
    brenth, ridder, and bisect, but they all require that the root
    first be bracketed in an interval where the function changes
    sign. The brentq algorithm is recommended for general use in one
    dimensional problems when such an interval has been found.

    """
    if tol <= 0:
        raise ValueError("tol too small (%g <= 0)" % tol)
    if fprime is not None:
        # Newton-Rapheson method
        # Multiply by 1.0 to convert to floating point.  We don't use float(x0)
        # so it still works if x0 is complex.
        p0 = 1.0 * x0
        fder2 = 0
        for iter in range(maxiter):
            myargs = (p0,) + args
```

> ```
>           fder = fprime(*myargs)
> ```
>
> E               TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable

`File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\zeros.py", line 116
TypeError`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what's happening is that you're passing in the value of a derivative, rather than a function representing the derivative. You need something that is "callable" and a value (more specifically the value `dfx0 = derivative(f, 2.0)`) is unable to be "called" like a function.

FYI: If you haven't already, it might be a good idea to take a look at [these examples](https://sites.google.com/a/aims-senegal.org/scipy/roots-finding-numerical-integrations-and-differential-equations).

Comment: So I would have to declare 'x' a symbolic variable and use sympy to compute the derivative df of f? How do I get a python function back for the derivative df?

Comment: No -- you need to define a function for the derivative. You've defined `f`. How would you define the derivative of `f`?

Comment: @jjack: You might try something like this: `newton(f, 2.0, lambda x: 2*x)`

Comment: The problem is that I just used x**2 as an example. I'm really trying to evaluate a function in terms of `Gamma(1+3/x)/Gamma(1+1/x)**3`.

Comment: I guess I'll just have to do it by hand. But it would be nice to know Python can handle this, too.

Comment: @jjack I don't understand...was my suggestion unhelpful?

Comment: No, it helped. I just wanted to compute the derivative symbolically, not manually. Thank you.

Comment: @jjack: You might want to check [this](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/calculus.html) out then.

Comment: I posted an answer showing how you can compute the derivative and evaluate it using SymPy.

Answer (score 3):

You can use SymPy to evaluate the derivative, and then use `lambdify` to convert that expression into a function that can be used with scipy. Note that `lambdify` currently doesn't know about SciPy by default, so you'll have to add a translation dictionary for the scipy special functions manually:

```
In [23]: expr = gamma(1+3/x)/gamma(1+1/x)**3

In [24]: print(expr.diff(x))
3*gamma(1 + 3/x)*polygamma(0, 1 + 1/x)/(x**2*gamma(1 + 1/x)**3) - 3*gamma(1 + 3/x)*polygamma(0, 1 + 3/x)/(x**2*gamma(1 + 1/x)**3)

In [25]: f = lambdify(x, expr.diff(x), ['numpy', {'gamma': scipy.special.gamma, 'polygamma': scipy.special.polygamma}])
```

At this point, I am not able to find any roots of this expression using the `newton` function. Based on the graph of the original from [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Gamma(1%2B3%2Fx)%2FGamma(1%2B1%2Fx)**3&dataset=), I don't see any obvious points where the derivative is 0, so I wouldn't be surprised if there are no real roots.

Comment: The function 'expr' doesn't have any roots. But if you subtract its y-value at a point from it and compute the root of the resulting function f =  gamma(1+3/x)/gamma(1+1/x)**3-y0, then you get the inverse x0 of 'expr' at the point y0. Thanks for your answer using lambdify, that'll help.

Comment: I mean the derivative has no roots. It looks like the original has no roots as well (which is a coincidence, mathematically speaking).